# Salvar clique no localStorage

Tags: jquery, localstorage

Tenho um botão simples que quando clicado o seu texto muda - e ao clicado novamente volta ao texto anterior. Assim:

```
<button class="texto">texto 1</button>

<scprit>
    $('.texto').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('texto');
        if($this.hasClass('texto')){
            $this.text('texto 1');          
        } else {
            $this.text('texto 2');
        }
    });
</scprit>
```

Preciso que fique salvo no localStorage, quando o usuário recarregar a página ainda esteja do ultimo modo como ele clicou.
Me ajudem, por favor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, tenta da seguinte forma:

```
<button class="texto">texto 1</button>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var savedText = localStorage.getItem('click');

  if(savedText) {
    $('.texto').text(savedText);
  }
});

$('.texto').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('texto');
    if($this.hasClass('texto')){
        $this.text('texto 1');
    } else {
        $this.text('texto 2');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('click', $this.text());
});
```

Comment: aeee! cara que entende é foda dms hehe. obrigado!!

Comment: vi que se eu usar mais de um botão com a mesma classe, ao clicar, muda apenas ela. Porém, todas as outras se salvam no localStorage porque quando recarrego a página todas estão com o mesmo valor daquela uma clicada. vc saberia fazer com que apenas aquela (this) fosse salva? ou seria necessário criar um sisteminha desses pra cada uma? (e eu tenho muuuitos botões com o mesmo efeito, seria terrivel kkkk)

Comment: Trabalhe com ID e não com class pra evitar isso, para utilizar o ID no JQuery, utilize o # no lugar do .

Comment: o problema é que não pegaria as várias classes que é necessário, teria que fazer uma por uma...